# Exeption on .toPromise() in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

I call to the server using the promises model. If I add `.toPromise()` then I catch the exception in the console.

[image]

When I remove `.toPromise()`; everything is ok, but I need it cuz I need await for response.

My code:

```
async getSettings(): Promise<any> {
 const ress = await this.http.get<string>(`api/${environment.apiVersion}/settings`).toPromise();
 console.log(ress);
}
```

I added `.then()` and, in general, did it like here under the link https://www.positronx.io/angular-promises-example-manage-http-requests/ but I have the same result. What I do wrong?

Comment: once you await it its not a promise anymore, it should be resolved to the returned value.. try removing the await and returning the res..

Comment: You need to return ress at the end. It's still asynchronous outside the function if you call await, it just has an imperative feel. Return ress at the end, and also please add the exception details to the question if you still get one.

Comment: I remove await and dont wait for result and still have exeption https://prnt.sc/usmiyt

Comment: Leave the await, wrap it in a try catch, print the exception, should get more detail.

Comment: In catch I has this "OK" such in screenshot. I dont know how to understand it

Comment: Note that `toPromise()` is [being deprecated](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/) in RxJS 7 and gone in RxJS 8.

Comment: In that example you've linked in, there's no await. Remove that await. Also: why would you "await" for the result, but then give the result asynchronously to the caller?

Comment: You'd also want to resolve the promise by using those blocks in the "then" call. The second block "err =>" is where your exception could be logged. Put a console.log(err) there... and show us your console again.

Comment: @JanosVinceller I wrote about it in previous comment. If I remove await I will not wait for responce, but I need it!